# Why TypeScript refuse sytacs of checkbox input?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

Following checkbox is functional, but TypeScript raise warning:

```js
<input
  type="checkbox"
  onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setIsTOSAccepted(event.target.checked);
  }}
  defaultChecked={isTOSAccepted}
/>
```

```
Failed to compile.

./pages/hu/buyTicket/[eventId].tsx:530:49
Type error: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

  528 |                 style={{ marginRight: "16px" }}
  529 |                 onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
> 530 |                   setIsTOSAccepted(event.target.checked);
      |                                                 ^
  531 |                 }}
  532 |                 defaultChecked={isTOSAccepted}
  533 |               />
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried replace `React.MouseEvent` with other type of events, and also replace `HTMLInputElement` witout any luck.

I checked here the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

but `HTMLInputElement` has `click` event and `checked` property. Strange.

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget.checked` instead. `currentTarget` will always be the `<input>`. `target` could be any random child element.

Comment: why does the second snippet says button element `event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` ?

Comment: ahh, I tried Button.. also, but `currentTarget` helped

Answer (score 3):

In general, when an element with an event listener is clicked, the *target* may not necessarily be that element.

```js
outer.onclick = (e) => console.log(e.target);
```

```html
<div id=outer>
  outer
  <div id=inner>inner</div>
</div>
```

Although inputs may not have children, that's a detail TypeScript doesn't parse and recognize - you have to refer to the `.currentTarget` instead, which will reference the element the listener was attached to.

```
setIsTOSAccepted(event.currentTarget.checked);
```

You can also simplify

```
onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
```

to

```
onClick={(event) => {
```

since TS will already know what the type of the `event` is.